# Should I dispose FontFamily.Families result?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, dispose, idisposable

Should I dispose each font in `System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families` property, which returns me an array of `FontFamily` class which implements `IDisposable`?

Should I dispose any other class instances or array of instances which also implement `IDisposable` in that rare cases when they are returned by a property accessor?

Comment: No.  It is fine to do the same thing that FontCollection.Dispose() does.  Nothing.  Feel better about it by testing it, add a button that runs the code 10000 times.  Look at your program with Task Manager, add the Handles, USER Objects and GDI Objects columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the code using Reflector, and I can tell you that when you access that property, a load of Font handles are being allocated using `SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCloneFontFamily()` for each font.

You should if it isn't too hard. If you do not, the finalizer will free the OS handle allocated for each font, but if there are a lot of fonts you don't really want to take a long time to dispose them. It could take an arbitrarily long time before the finalizer is called.

If you were accessing the `Families[]` property repeatedly, you could end up with a lot of unreleased OS handles which could cause problems.

Here's the Dispose() method for the `FontFamily` type:

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.nativeFamily != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        try
        {
            SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDeleteFontFamily(new HandleRef(this, this.nativeFamily));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (ClientUtils.IsCriticalException(exception))
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.nativeFamily = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you would be missing out on the call to `GdipDeleteFontFamily()` which would be freeing underlying the OS handle for the font.

(Sidenote: Microsoft's documentation for this kind of thing is very poor, because their sample code typically ignores the issue of disposing fonts.)

Here's the implementation of `Families`:

```
public FontFamily[] Families
{
    get
    {
        int numFound = 0x0;
        int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetFontCollectionFamilyCount(new HandleRef(this, this.nativeFontCollection), out numFound);
        if (status != 0x0)
        {
            throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
        }
        IntPtr[] gpfamilies = new IntPtr[numFound];
        int num3 = 0x0;
        status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetFontCollectionFamilyList(new HandleRef(this, this.nativeFontCollection), numFound, gpfamilies, out num3);
        if (status != 0x0)
        {
            throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
        }
        FontFamily[] familyArray = new FontFamily[num3];
        for (int i = 0x0; i < num3; i++)
        {
            IntPtr ptr;
            SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCloneFontFamily(new HandleRef(null, gpfamilies[i]), out ptr);
            familyArray[i] = new FontFamily(ptr);
        }
        return familyArray;
    }
}
```

Note how it counts how many fonts there are, and then calls `GdipCloneFontFamily()` for each one and initialises a new `FontFamily` with the returned `IntPtr`.

Comment: Shouldn't the framework return the same instance of `FontFamily.Families` property each time? Rather than it would be a method which whould generate each time different FontFamilies?

Comment: @AgentFire You might expect that, but the implementation of `Families` creates it anew each time. I'll add the implementation to my answer.

Comment: Is there any real documentation relating to font resource ownership within WinForms?  Will a plain-old derivative of `Control` have a GDI font resource allocated for its `Font` property somewhere?  Is there any way it can use it?

Comment: @supercat I've never found any real documentation about this. The form code generator doesn't seem to care much about disposing fonts...